# Passing variables from NPM Scripts to Webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, npm-scripts

I have a production build with Webpack that uses node's `process.env` to set environment variables:

**webpack.prod.babel.js:**

```
const DefinePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
    API_URL: JSON.stringify('https://myprodurl.com'),
  },
});
```

**packge.json:**

```
"scripts: {
  "build:prod": "webpack"
}
```

It's working fine, but I need something different.

**I need to set the production url as variable in the NPM Script**.

So, instead of this:

```
npm run build:prod
```

I need this:

```
npm run build:prod --URL https://myprodurl.com
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about defining your environment variable in the command line, like:

`URL=https://myprodurl.com npm run build:prod`

I tested this with a simple script and was able to print out the `URL`.

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./myTest.js"
},
```

myTest.js:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

'use strict'

console.log(process.env.URL);
console.log('Done!');
```

then:

```
$ URL=https://whatever.com npm run test

> my-test@1.0.0 test /Test/my-test
> ./myTest.js

https://whatever.com
Done!
```

EDIT: As mentioned by @RyanZim, see the following for Windows: https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env
(disclaimer: I don't use Windows and have never tried this lib)

Comment: Should be edited to mention that if you need windows support, you will have to use https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env.

Comment: instead of creating a whole new script file, you can just prepend environment variables to your `npm run` command: `"build:prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack"`

Comment: You're close, but your code should be `API_URL: JSON.stringify( process.env.URL ),` to correctly answer the question

Comment: @DanO  Good point. You could definitely put it in the command line of your `scripts` entry inside `package.json` to simplify it.

Comment: @AndyRay Sorry, was just trying to give a simple working example.